# unable to add event using EventKit in iOS app

Tags: ios, eventkit

I am trying to add event in iOS app using Event kit with following code:

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (!granted) { return; }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        event.title = eventName;
        event.startDate = [NSDate dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[arrEvent objectAtIndex:1],[arrEvent objectAtIndex:2]] withFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"];
        event.endDate = [NSDate dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[arrEvent objectAtIndex:1],[arrEvent objectAtIndex:3]] withFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"];
        [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        NSError *err = nil;
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

        NSString *savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier;  //this is so you can access this event later
        NSLog(@"%@",savedEventId);
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Event added to calendar" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"View Calendar", nil];
        alert.tag = 101;
        [alert show];
    });
}];
```

But I am getting granted as false so it doesn't add the event. It is not working in my simulator and device both, even after I reset my simulator. Same code works in another app of mine. Can someone please suggest me what I should do?
**Edit:** Error is always nil

Comment: If `granted` is `NO`, log `error` to see why.

Comment: I see no error and granted is no. I don't also get alert for accepting or denying access to calendar

Answer (score 1):

When app launched for first time, a message asking for permissions will be shown to the user, and app will be able to access the calendar if only the user granted permission. In your case you have declined permission for calendar.

For fixing this issue, Go to Settings ->  -> Allow  to access calendar = YES.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're requesting to get the access every time. You should better check the authorisation status first and if it's not determined, only then request for the authorisation. First check this using "authorizationStatusForEntityType" and create a new method to save the event, not inside "requestAccessToEntityType".